# Exception has occurred: ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, django

I have this error when try to debug the code:

```
Exception has occurred: ImproperlyConfigured
Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
  File "C:\PyProjects\InstaDriver\users_app\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
```

The error stop my code like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KwNY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you are starting your app from wrong place, your start point should be manage.py, default behavior of vscode is your current file in your case views.py